# How can I ask the Selenium-WebDriver to wait until one of elements display

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have a page that display (using ajax) one of  `div#div1` or `div#div2`  elements randomly. how can i wait until one of these elements display on page?

```
   browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
   browser_wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)

   browser.get("http://www.myweb.com")

   element = browser_wait.until { 
   #       browser.find_element(:css => "div#div1") || 
   #       browser.find_element(:css => "div#div2") 
   }
```

what can i use instead of commented lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an "or" in a CSS-selector by using a comma between selectors. For example, the following CSS-selector will wait for a div with id "div1" or a div with id "div2":

```css
div#div1, div#div2
```

You can use this locator when finding the element:

```ruby
element = browser_wait.until { 
  browser.find_element(:css, 'div#div1, div#div2')
}
```

`element` will be whichever div is found (or the first on the page if both exist).